# What does the pipe character do in Racket?

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

The reader interprets `|` in a special way, however I cannot find any documentation on it. Does anyone have any idea what this symbol means to Racket?

Comment: More context?  Otherwise one of the below wins if we happened to hit upon the context you are interested in.

Comment: @GoZoner I made a typo in the REPL earlier and noticed that `|` meant something, so it looks like Rainer's answer applies to my context.

Comment: Okay, at least give all the answers an 'upvote'...

Comment: @GoZoner Done, they are all good answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the Racket syntax:

http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html

> | starts a subsequence of characters to be included verbatim in the delimited sequence (i.e., they are never treated as delimiters, and they are not case-folded when case-insensitivity is enabled); the subsequence is terminated by another |, and neither the initial nor terminating | is part of the subsequence.

For example 1.3.2 Reading Symbols.

Answer (score 3):

The pipe is part of the multiline comments syntax:

```
#|
commented text
|#
```

Answer (score 2):

See [Racket Scribble Syntax](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/reader.html); lots of `|`'s used there.  Its use depends on the context.